# Difference in difference with multiple treatments

Tags: difference-in-difference, research-design

I have a setting in which there are three disjoint groups as follows; (1) a group which does not experience any change, i.e., controls, (2) a group who receives treatment 1, and (3) and a group who receives treatment 2 which includes treatment 1.

I am aware of the DD setup with discrete treatment at varying levels which gives the effect of the treatments relative to the controls, but in my case, the effect of interest is the the difference between groups 2 and 3, in order to isolate the effect of treatment 2.

Ideally, I need a design that would give me all the possible pairwise comparisons, i.e., the outcome differences between groups 1&2, 1&3, and also 2&3.

Comment: Is there any treatment overlap? For example, is there some time frame where a unit is getting treatment one, but then at a later point in time they receive treatment two? In short, yes it’s possible to isolate the effect of the second treatment, but I’m not sure that’s what you really want. Do you want the independent effect of each treatment, or do you want to look at how these different treatments interact with each other?

Comment: I need independent treatment effect for the second treatment, but the problem is that first and second treatment only happen at the same time and together. I also have a group which only experiences the first treatment, which conceptually should enable me to isolate the second treatment, but I do not know how!
For example, in a policy roll out setup, assume there are some states which enacted laws A and B at the same time, some states only law A, and some states none. I want to isolate the effect of law B.